# Add rows to CSV File in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Trying to figure out how to add a row to a csv file with titles.
I get the content using:

```
$fileContent = Import-csv $file -header "Date", "Description"
```

`$File` returns

```
Date,Description
Text1,text2 
text3,text4
```

How do I append a row with a new date and description. Sorry I am relatively new to powershell. thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more careful when choosing the tags for your questions. I edited yours to be more appropriate to your question. (Tags are used for grouping questions into categories by topic or subject, and your original tag of `stackoverflow.com` was not only inappropriate, but had absolutely nothing to do with your question.) You might also want to visit the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to familiarize yourself with the site in general. :)

Answer (score 23):

To simply append to a file in powershell,you can use add-content.

So, to only add a new line to the file, try the following, where $YourNewDate and $YourDescription contain the desired values.

```
$NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $YourNewDate,$YourDescription
$NewLine | add-content -path $file
```

Or,

```
"{0},{1}" -f $YourNewDate,$YourDescription | add-content -path $file
```

This will just tag the new line to the end of the .csv, and will not work for creating new .csv files where you will need to add the header.

Comment: Thank you marceljg. I was exactly looking for the same solution and your one liner works perfect for me.

Comment: just wondering is there a simple way to prepend the added rows rather then appending?

Answer (score 15):

Create a new custom object and add it to the object array that `Import-Csv` creates.

```
$fileContent = Import-csv $file -header "Date", "Description"
$newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Date = 'Text4' ; Description = 'Text5' }
$fileContent += $newRow
```

Comment: This worked great for me except that it changed the ordering of my columns. After I appended the line using the above answer I had to use `$Import = $Import | Select-Object...` to re-order my columns for export.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread but it was the first I found when searching. The +=  solution did not work for me. The code that I did get to work is as below.

```
#this bit creates the CSV if it does not already exist
$headers = "Name", "Primary Type"
$psObject = New-Object psobject
foreach($header in $headers)
{
 Add-Member -InputObject $psobject -MemberType noteproperty -Name $header -Value ""
}
$psObject | Export-Csv $csvfile -NoTypeInformation

#this bit appends a new row to the CSV file
$bName = "My Name"
$bPrimaryType = "My Primary Type"
    $hash = @{
             "Name" =  $bName
             "Primary Type" = $bPrimaryType
              }

$newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property $hash
Export-Csv $csvfile -inputobject $newrow -append -Force
```

I was able to use this as a function to loop through a series of arrays and enter the contents into the CSV file.

It works in powershell 3 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Simple to me is like this:

```
$Time = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm K"
$Description = "Done on time"

"$Time,$Description"|Add-Content -Path $File # Keep no space between content variables
```

If you have a lot of columns, then create a variable like `$NewRow` like:

```
$Time = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm K"
$Description = "Done on time"
$NewRow = "$Time,$Description" # No space between variables, just use comma(,).

$NewRow | Add-Content -Path $File # Keep no space between content variables
```

Please note the difference between `Set-Content` (overwrites the existing contents) and `Add-Content` (appends to the existing contents) of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I find using `$newRowToAdd | Export-Csv -Append` the easiest way. Not sure which version that was introduced though