# report veritas Backupexec 16 list of servers with last succesful job associated

Tags: powershell, backupexec

I am using the PowerShell module BEMCLI and I want to create a report with these columns: list of servers, Jobs associated to the server with the last successful run.

I can get the list of servers with: `Get-BEAgentServer`

I can get also the list of jobs in success in a period with:

```
Get-BEJobHistory -JobStatus Succeeded -FromStartTime (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) | ft -auto
```

Is there an easy way to get what I want?

Comment: See PowerShell `Select-Object` cmdlet and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813228/add-rows-to-csv-file-in-powershell).

Comment: Can you create your report in `CSV`? If so then, I see that you will need to add columns and not reports to your `CSV`. If that's the case, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022017/add-column-to-csv-windows-powershell) link might be useful.

Comment: yes i can creat the report in CSV , now i can get the list of job of a server by: $Servers=GET-BEAgentServer
ForEach ($server in $Servers)
{
$listJob=Get-BEAgentServer | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq $server)} | Get-BEJob 
}

Comment: i want to put in csv file , in every sheet the name of a sheet= name of server (i can get that on variable $server.name ) , in every put the output of the command in columns , how can i do this in a easy way ?  script: